# ssh to remote host from a list of hosts from a file

Tags: ssh

What to use for loop to log into websevers using this command?

```
for host in $(cat remhost); do
   ssh devops@$host uptime;
done
```

keep getting:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname host: Name or service not known

what do I need to correct?

Comment: Nice that you've dropped by, but this forum is for ubuntu specific questions. Yours is a general linux question (since you didn't even wrote which Ubuntu version you are using). [This site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) will gladly answer your questions without asking which distro and version you are using ;-)

Comment: @kanehekili [Are bash/shell scripting questions on topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic)

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, if we roam in the Ubuntu universe:`Shell scripting is an integral part of managing a Linux system`

Comment: It is hard to say why it is showing `host` since we don't know what the format of your `remhost` file is.